# send data with form 2 html js

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
First Name:
<INPUT type="text" ><br>

<input type="radio"><br>

<input type="checkbox"><br>

<input type="textarea">

</FORM>

<FORM action="file.php" method="post" name=form1>

<INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</FORM>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/674brq05/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but you can get the form information from JS:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunc()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" id="name">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The above does so the function "myFunc()" runs on submit.
And then the JS:

```
function myFunc() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  alert(name.value);
  return false; // Return false to cancel the submit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Way to take two form tag for submitting one form:

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm" action="action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```